# Scroll function called automatically when modal open and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal which contains scrollable div `id=moreContent` and modal is open when a button is clicked. but the problem if I close the div with the scroll bar and then I try to reopen the modal the scroll function is also called. what am I doing wrong here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#buttonId").click(function() {
    $('#myModal').openModal();
  });

  $("#moreContent").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this[0].scrollHeight) {
        console.log("this should be called only if manually scrolled ??");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myModal {
  max-height: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  min-height: 700px;
  max-width: 912px;
  min-width: 912px;
  width: 912px;
}

#moreContent {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal confirm-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="moreContent">
      <div id="moreSupervisorContent"></div>
      <div id="moreSubordinateContent" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your modal is changing the size of the document. When the document changes size, the scroll position changes, thus triggering a scroll event.

This is most likely due to the fact that your modal has a fixed height. Setting fixed sizes is typically a bad idea in web development since you can't predict how big someone's screen or browser will be.

To solve it, you should style your modal an `absolute` or `fixed` position, set it to 100% height and have it handle the overflow instead of `#moreContent`. The `position` will keep the document from growing and the modal will only show scrollbars if its content gets larger than it is.

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal__content {
  height: 700px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__content">
    <h3>This is the modal content</h3>
    <p>This is some content inside the modal and it is fixed to 700px height</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>This is the page</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum luctus leo pharetra sodales. Donec quis imperdiet odio, interdum hendrerit libero. Phasellus sollicitudin pellentesque turpis, vitae sagittis augue sagittis sit amet. Aenean pretium augue in pharetra tempor. Aenean tempus vulputate dui, eget blandit eros vulputate a. Morbi et laoreet metus, non sollicitudin ex. Phasellus egestas, magna et malesuada bibendum, dolor nisl gravida nunc, sit amet pulvinar nisl leo eu neque. Etiam eget orci ac velit porttitor euismod. Aenean accumsan condimentum egestas. Donec dictum laoreet mi, eu auctor ante sagittis id. Integer lacinia bibendum porta.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum luctus leo pharetra sodales. Donec quis imperdiet odio, interdum hendrerit libero. Phasellus sollicitudin pellentesque turpis, vitae sagittis augue sagittis sit amet. Aenean pretium augue in pharetra tempor. Aenean tempus vulputate dui, eget blandit eros vulputate a. Morbi et laoreet metus, non sollicitudin ex. Phasellus egestas, magna et malesuada bibendum, dolor nisl gravida nunc, sit amet pulvinar nisl leo eu neque. Etiam eget orci ac velit porttitor euismod. Aenean accumsan condimentum egestas. Donec dictum laoreet mi, eu auctor ante sagittis id. Integer lacinia bibendum porta.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum luctus leo pharetra sodales. Donec quis imperdiet odio, interdum hendrerit libero. Phasellus sollicitudin pellentesque turpis, vitae sagittis augue sagittis sit amet. Aenean pretium augue in pharetra tempor. Aenean tempus vulputate dui, eget blandit eros vulputate a. Morbi et laoreet metus, non sollicitudin ex. Phasellus egestas, magna et malesuada bibendum, dolor nisl gravida nunc, sit amet pulvinar nisl leo eu neque. Etiam eget orci ac velit porttitor euismod. Aenean accumsan condimentum egestas. Donec dictum laoreet mi, eu auctor ante sagittis id. Integer lacinia bibendum porta.</p>
```

Comment: isn't there anyway that I can continue with fixed modal height ?

Comment: isn't there anyway I can continue with fixed modal height ?

I tried, setting $(#moreContent).scrollTop(0) when opening modal but it didn't work

Comment: You can make the *contents* of the modal, to be 700px, but that's because the modal container itself should have an overflow set on it. Remember, there's a container (the part that overlaps the screen and makes it darker) and the modal window itself.

Comment: @motabul I've updated my answer with an example of the styles I was talking about.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to have a div inside the modal with scrollble and modal height need to be fixed. and the problem is when the scrollble div get higher than it defined and when I close it, an event bind for that div scroll function is called which I don't need to happen

Comment: @motabul Then set `overflow: hidden` instead of `auto` so that the browser cuts it off rather than adding scrollbars and set your content region to scroll. What you're asking for is very fragile and is why your scroll events keep firing.